# How to set up this vector problem?

Tags: physics

Reading through my homework, I encountered this.  I don't know what a picture of this would look like, and how to decompose into separate vectors.  Once I figure out what I need to decompose into, I can do the rest.  Can you help me?

> A car is driven east for a distance of 48 km, then north for 27 km,
>   and then in a direction 32° east of north for 25 km. Determine (a) the
>   magnitude (in km) of the car's total displacement from its starting
>   point and (b) the angle (from east) of the car's total displacement
>   measured from its starting direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a picture. Piece by piece. Describing what it looks like just involves me repeating the problem. Draw a line segment right and label is 40. Draw a line segment up and label it 27, connected to the end of the previous line. Draw a line segment at an angle, label the degree 32 from upwards and the length 25. Then find the overall x and y displacement for the big triangle.

Answer (score 1):

HINT Take the unit vector along (positive) east to be $\mathbf i = (1,0)$, and that along north to be $\mathbf j = (0,1)$. Now, consider each of the three displacements, and decompose them into $\mathbf i$ and $\mathbf j$ components. The final position is just the vector sum of the displacements.